# VBA Excel - Delete - Cannot use that command on overlapping selections

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to apply filter to the data and copy the filtered data to an other sheet and delete the filtered rows in base sheet.

I am facing error as '**cannot use the command on overlapping selection**'

When I try to delete the filtered rows in base sheet using

`specialcells(xlcelltypevisible).entirerow.delete`

```
Sheets("analysis").select
Sourcecol=1
VCurrLength = cells(rows.count, sourcecol).end(clip).row
Activesheet.range("$A$1:$W$"& VCurrLength).autofilter field:=7, criteria1:= "ZP"
Range ("A1").select
Selection.end(xldown).select
If selection.row<1000000 then
    Range("A2:w"& VCurrLength).specialcells(xlcelltypevisible).copy
    Sheets("temp").select
    Activesheet.paste
    
    Sheets("analysis").select
    Range("A2:w"& VCurrLength).specialcells(xlcelltypevisible).select
    Selection.entirerow.delete
Endif
```

Comment: Could you share the complete code?

Comment: It appears the `Range` you are deleting contains overlapping selections. Without showing us the actual relevant code, that's about as deep as answers can go...

Comment: Code has been missed while post the question. Regret for the cause. Kindly check once now. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Backup Data

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub backupData()
    
    Dim Success As Boolean
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("analysis")
    Dim sLR As Long: sLR = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1:W" & sLR)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then
        sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    srg.AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:="ZP"
    If WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, srg.Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
        Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("temp")
        Dim dcell As Range
        Set dcell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Dim frg As Range
        Set frg = srg.Resize(srg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) _
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        frg.Copy dcell
        frg.EntireRow.Delete
        If Not sws Is ActiveSheet Then
            sws.Activate
        End If
        srg.Cells(1).Select
        Success = True
    End If
    
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    If Success Then
        MsgBox "Data updated.", vbInformation, "Success"
    Else
        MsgBox "No updates available.", vbExclamation, "Nope"
    End If
    
End Sub
```